# Helper method to shuffle cards list for online gaming

Tags: c#, random, extension-methods, shuffle

I have written this code to shuffle a deck of cards. I would like to hear your inputs.

```
public static class Helper
{

    public static Int32 GetRandomNo(this RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng, byte[] data)
    {
        rng.GetBytes(data);
        var randomNo = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
        return randomNo;
    }

    public static void Shuffle<T>(this List<T> source)
    {
        using (RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            // Buffer storage.
            byte[] data = new byte[4];

            source =
                source.Select(element => new {element, randomValue = rng.GetRandomNo(data)})
                    .OrderBy(entry => entry.randomValue)
                    .Select(entry => entry.element)
                    .ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd suspect you've already seen [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt)?

Comment: I have seen that thread, but the approach I am taking is I think different. So wanted to submit the approach for a review to see how good is it from say solns from that thread. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

4 bytes is only 4,294,967,296
Consider there are 52! possible shuffles = 8 * 10^67

Use a proper shuffle like [Fisher Yates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). You get a proper shuffle with only 0-51 random.  Also shuffle from the prior shuffle (not a sorted deck). If you look closely Fisher Yates it produces exactly 52! deals.  It is perfect.

I am not sure about your algorithm but I think the problem is that it will produce too many shuffles and they will not have uniform distribution.  I think it will produce 52^52 deals.

A perfect random with a less than perfect algorithm is a bigger vulnerability than a perfect algorithm and a less than perfect random.

You can use the regular Random and a proper algorithm and not be exploited unless they know the seed.  But it does not hurt to use RNGCryptoServiceProvider.

[Poker security](http://www.developer.com/tech/article.php/10923_616221_3/How-We-Learned-to-Cheat-at-Online-Poker-A-Study-in-Software-Security.htm)

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry, I misread the code. I thought that the total randomness would be 32 bits.

Comment: Thanks for the wise words : "A perfect random with a less than perfect algorithm is a bigger vulnerability than a perfect algorithm and a less than perfect random." -:)

Answer (score 1):

I wonder that the linked SO question does not mention the  `Sort` method. With it you can randomize the list in place by creating a custom `Comparison<T>`. You should also return the new result so you can chain other extensions if necessary.

```
public static List<T> Shuffle<T>(this List<T> source)
{
    using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        var data = new byte[4];
        source.Sort(CompareRandomNumbers<T>(data, rng.GetRandomNo));            
        return source;
    }
}

private static Comparison<T> CompareRandomNumbers<T>(byte[] data, Func<byte[], int> getRandomNumber)
{
    return (x, y) => getRandomNumber(data).CompareTo(getRandomNumber(data));
}
```

Usage:

```
var randomizedList = new[] { "a", "b", "c", "d" }.ToList().Shuffle();
```

Comment: Doesn't this code violate the contract for `CompareTo`?

Comment: @RolandIllig in which way? We are not interested in comparing the actual elements because we randomizing the list so instead we compare random numbers.

Comment: It looks as if `getRandomNumber`is called more than once for each element. If so, `CompareTo` doesn't describe an ordering anymore.